# How can I update the same SqlServer record inside a sqlsrv_fetch_array loop?

Tags: php, sql-server, loops

This is production code, so I don't have the option of checking for errors.
The SqlProfile trace shows the update is tried 7 times.

```
$query = "Select pkey, field1 from Table1 with (NOLOCK) where etc ....;";
$unitsrs  = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query) or die('sqlsrv error: ' . print_r( sqlsrv_errors()) );

while($unitsrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($unitsrs)) {
    $pkey = $unitsrow['pkey'];
    $field1   = $unitsrow['field1'];

    $newvalue = 0;
    ...
    $update = "Update Table1 Set Field1 = $newvalue where pkey = '$pkey';";
    sqlsrv_query($conn, $update);

}
```

Comment: do you get any error ? make sure about your update query .

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon from update query

```
   $update = "Update Table1 Set Field1 = $newvalue where pkey = '$pkey'";
```